# Can we write an if statement backwards in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between these two expressions?

```
if (userStatus === 'OFFLINE') document.forms.newMessage.fields.disabled = true;
```

and

```
document.forms.newMessage.fields.disabled = (userStatus === 'OFFLINE');
```

Comment: in the first case, the field is only overwritten if the user is offline, in the second case always. Consider the case where that `userStatus` is not offline

Comment: `userStatus = "OFFLINE"` - no difference. `userStatus = "ONLINE"` - the first one will *not* set the `disabled`, the second one *will* set it to `false`. Whether that matters or not depends on how exactly is this property going to be used. So, there is no generic answer - a property *missing* and a property being *set to false* are technically different things with different meanings. They might be handled the same way in some cases. In *this* specific case you'd get the same result just because that's how form elements handle this situation.

Comment: That is actually wrong because they both work the exact same way. I know this because I have already implemented them in my app. The input with the name fields in newMessage form only get disabled attribute when the value is OFFLINE

Comment: @TarasiCristiAndrei again, there is no generic answer to this. All we can say is that the semantics of the two pieces of code are completely different. They *could* be handled the same way and indeed they are *in the context of form elements*. However, that's not going to be applicable in every single case. Consider [this](https://jsbin.com/yiticayura/edit?js,console) and [this](https://jsbin.com/vuwidaxawo/1/edit?js,console) - these are definitely *different* results.

Comment: btw, you do not need parentheses aroun the comparison. the assignment evaluates the rhs expression first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.forms.newMessage.fields.disabled = (userStatus === 'OFFLINE')
```

is equivalent to

```
if (userStatus === 'OFFLINE') { 
    document.forms.newMessage.fields.disabled = true;
} else {
    document.forms.newMessage.fields.disabled = false;
}
```

Notice the else statement. If there is no else statement then your first piece of code only sets `document.forms.newMessage.fields.disabled` when the condition `(userStatus === 'OFFLINE')` is met.

---

Consider the case  in which
`document.forms.newMessage.fields.disabled` is already true but `userStatus` is `"ONLINE"`.

With your first piece of code, `document.forms.newMessage.fields.disabled` will remain true (because of the lack of else statement) , but with the second piece of code, it will be set to false.